# How can I install PyTango 7.2 in a virtualenv on Debian 7?

Tags: python, debian, virtualenv, tango-controls

I am able to install PyTango 7.2 on Debian 7 using:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pytango #installs on system, not virtualenv
```

However, I need to install it in a Python virtualenv. I have created a virtualenv and installed the following prerequisites, but it still doesn't compile:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pytango #so this anyway to install some prerequisites
sudo apt-get install libboost-python-dev #additional prerequisite for compilation
workon virtualenvname
easy_install PyTango-7.2.4.tar.gz
```

I get:

```
Processing PyTango-7.2.4.tar.gz
Running PyTango-7.2.4/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-ZhyGFF/PyTango-7.2.4/egg-dist-tmp-psCoDv
/tmp/easy_install-ZhyGFF/PyTango-7.2.4/src/api_util.cpp:25:19: fatal error: tango.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I'm guessing that I can `apt-get install` an additional Tango package or two to make tango.h available, but which one? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the libtango7-dev package to get the header files.

You can search the contents of Debian packages here https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages#search_contents